# Numbers with more than n divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

1. Numbers with more than 4 divisors = multiples of numbers with exactly 4 divisors. This only applies to 4 (and 2, of course): e.g. numbers with more than 3 divisors != multiples of numbers with exactly 3 divisors.
2. Numbers with more than 5 divisors = multiples of [OEIS A068993](https://oeis.org/A068993)

My quick question is: are these two facts obvious and/or well-known?

I assume that the answer is "yes", but I know pretty much nothing about mathematics, so I wanted to ask this question. I would have asked it in the chat, but I have not enough reputation.

A simple yes/no answer is fine for me, but of course if you want to add an explanation, it's even better. :)

**Edit:** why I don't think this question was a duplicate. The answer is the same as the answer to [Finding out the number of divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942696/finding-out-the-number-of-divisors) (I have no reason to doubt it, even though I still have to understand the answer to my question!). But, as far as I can understand, "duplicate" applies to questions, not to answers. Otherwise, the following statement [from the help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) wouldn't make sense:

> [...] we love (some) dupes. There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way.

Now, my question is not the same as "finding out the number of divisors", so it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: I think the first is something that is a pretty routine reformation of the original statement. I'm kind of skeptical of statement 2; I think it's only a "subset" relation, rather than equality.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Don't see how this is a duplicate, sorry.

Comment: @pjs36 1. Could you please tell me what "the original statement" is? Thanks. 2. Based on my computations, it's equality, not just a subset.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I see that you have edited your comment, explaining why this is a duplicate. Thanks. I will read the Wikipedia page and reply as soon as possible (it won't be soon...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that numbers with more than four divisors are multiples of numbers with exactly four divisors are that the numbers exactly four divisors are of the form $pq$ for distinct primes $p,q$ or $p^3$ for prime $p$.  To have more than four, the number has to be of the form $p^4, p^2q, \text{ or } pqr$  for primes $p,q,r$ or more complex.  All of these are multiples of a number with exactly four factors.   Conversely, any multiple of a number $pq$ or $p^3$ will have more than four divisors.

A number with more than five divisors will be a multiple of a number in your OEIS sequence, because this sequence is all numbers of the form $pq$ or $p^4$.  As $pqr$ has eight divisors and $p^2q$ and $p^5$ have six, all multiples of the elements of this sequence will have more than five divisors.

Added:  for the fact that numbers with more that three divisors are not exactly the numbers that are multiples of numbers with exactly three divisors can be shown by example:  $6$ has four divisors, while $1,2,3$ do not have exactly three.  The general case is that a number of the form $pq$, with $p,q$ distinct primes, has factors $1,p,q,pq$ and none of $1,p,q$ have exactly three divisors.

Comment: There are 3 things I don't understand in the 1st answer (bet the problem is me!). 1) "All of these are multiples of a number with exactly four factors." This is the point to prove. Did you do it? 2) "Conversely, any multiple of a number pq or p^3 will have more than four divisors." Shouldn't we prove that "only multiples of [etc.]"? 3) You don't mention numbers with more than 3 or >4 divisors. Also, 2 questions about the 2nd answer: 4) "is all numbers of the form pqpq or p^4" Is this equivalent to the definition of the sequence? 5) Again, shouldn't "all multiples of" be "only multiples of"?

Comment: For 1, look at the factorization. If a number has any two distinct prime factors $p,q$, it is a multiple of $pq$, which has exactly four factors.  If it has only one prime factor, it is $p^k$ for $k \gt 3$, and is a multiple of $p^3$.  This proves more than four implies multiple of one with exactly four.  Then for 2 I am proving that multiple of a number with four implies more than four.  An even simpler way is to say a multiple of a number with four factors has those four plus itself (and maybe) more.

Comment: For the second question, yes, the sequence is all the numbers I  cited.  Multiplying by any number gives a result with a prime factorization that includes what I show, and then there will be more than five divisors.

Comment: For all these questions, you need to reflect on the divisor function given in the Wikipedia page I referenced above.  The number of divisors of a number is given by the pattern of exponents in its prime factorization.  If you want exactly $k$, you need to factor $k$ and establish the patterns that can do that.  That is where exactly 4 implies $p^3$ or $pq$ comes from and all the other claims I make.

Comment: I'm quite busy these days, but I plan to review the answers (and mark the best one) as soon as I can.

Comment: "For 1 [etc.]": OK. "Then for 2 I am proving that multiple of a number with four implies more than four": I still don't see how you proved it.

Comment: "yes, the sequence is all the numbers I cited": the equivalence is not explicited in the OEIS page; anyway, I accept your authority. "Multiplying by any number gives a result with a prime factorization that includes what I show, and then there will be more than five divisors": I still see this as "all multiples of the numbers in the sequence", not "only multiples [etc.]"; sorry. :(

Comment: To have more than four divisors means to have factors at least $pqr, p^2q,$ or $p^4$.  The first are multiples of $pq$, which has exactly four divisors.  The last is a multiple of $p^3$. I have shown an explicit divisor with exactly four factors for each number that has more than four.

Comment: As for my question 2-of-5: ...it was a very stupid question.

Comment: I _finally_ got why "numbers with more than 4 divisors = multiples of numbers with exactly 4 divisors". I still don't understand why this doesn't apply to any number >4. I'll get back at this.

Comment: For example, numbers with more than 5 divisors can be of the form $pqr$ and have eight divisors or $p^2q$ and have six divisors among other patterns.  The numbers with exactly 5 divisors are specifically of the form $p^4$, so numbers with more than 5 divisors may well not have a factor with exactly five divisors.

Comment: So there isn't a "general" reason for "numbers with more than n divisors = multiples of numbers with exactly n divisors" applying just to n=2 and n=4, right? If so, I can consider my question fully answered. Now I just have to check Sayantan Santra's answer and mark the "best" one for me.

Comment: While I appreciate both this answer and Sayantan Santra's, I've marked this as the best one because I feel this one is the most accessible to newbies like me, i.e. to the kind of people who could ask the questions I've asked.

Comment: It depends on the types of prime factorization that can give you more than $n$ divisors.  If you multiply by some prime that was not there before, you double the number of divisors, so generally those with more than $n$ may not be a multiple of one with exactly $n$.  $2$ and $4$ are small numbers, and that matters.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is a quite general reason. :)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the $\tau$ function is multiplicative. That means, $\tau(mn)=\tau(m)\tau(n)$ where $(m, n) =1$. But, as you seek intuition, I won't use it in the discussion. Now, your claim is true for $4$. The numbers which have $2$ divisors are prime $p$. Now, if we multiply it by something that the product has more than $4$ integers, then the multiplier must be of the form $p_1 p_2$ where at most one can be $p$ itself. But, we can always represent it as a multiple of $p_1 p_2$ which has exactly $4$ divisors. Now, a similar argument can be stated about integers with exactly $3$ divisors, which must be of the form $p^2$. So, every integer that has more than $4$ divisors can be expressed as a multiple of an integer with exactly $4$ divisors. But, no similar argument can be presented for numbers with higher divisor counts. Hence your claim is indeed true.

For the second case, just use the algebraic form of the $\tau$ function. Although, some simple combinatorics can give you the intuition.

Comment: "Now, a similar argument can be stated about integers with exactly 3 divisors": you don't mean that numbers with more than 3 divisors = multiples of numbers with 3 divisors, do you? Also, a hint of what kind of combinatorics can give me the intuition about the second problem would be nice; but if you don't care about explaining it to someone who should study rather than asking questions, I understand, :)

Comment: @milivella No, I meant that it can be easily shown that the multiples of those numbers which have more than $4$ divisors can be written as a multiple of a number with exactly $4$ divisors in a similar manner.

Comment: @milivella And, it's some elementary combinatorics. Factorise a number into primes and then try to work out a general form for its divisors. See how many are possible. That will show you how the $\tau$ function works.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand where "integers with exactly 3 divisors" fit. As for the second case, I guess my problem is that I don't understand the definition of OEIS A068993. Thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: @milivella Well, the problem could have been treated in a much more general way as some of the answers suggest but as you had requested insights, I decided to write it in the most informal way I could device. What I did is I simply showed that every integer with more than $4$ divisors can be expressed as the multiple of a number of exactly $4$ divisors which is equivalent to your claim.

Comment: @milivella You can take as a proof using contradiction. Suppose, I'm saying that the claim isn't true. So, there must be some exceptions. So, they must be multiples of numbers of exactly $2$ or $3$ divisors. Now, that makes them multiples of numbers of exactly $4$ divisors as we have shown. Contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

If a number is product of distinct primes then it has a power of $2$ number of divisors (it has $2^{\omega(n)}$ divisors, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of prime divisors of $n$).

So if your number is product of distinct primes all of its divisors has a power of $2$ number of divisors.

From here we deduce if $k$ is not a power of $2$ then there is a number $n$ such that $n$ has more than $k$ divisors and no divisor of $n$ has exactly $k$ multiples. We just take $p_1p_2\dots p_r$, where $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime and $2^r>k$.

So now we just have to check $2$ and $4$ are the only such powers of $2$ that work. To see this just now that $p_1^2p_2^2\dots p_r^2$ has $3^r$ divisors, and any divisor of this number that has a power of $2$ number of divisors has at most $2^r$ divisors.

So we must now all we must prove is that given $2^n$ with $n>2$ there is an $r<n$ so that $3^r>2^n$ , so all we must prove is $3^{n-1}>2^{n}\iff \frac{3}{2}^{n-1}>1$, which of course is true when $n>2$. Since $\frac{3}{2}^2=\frac{9}{4}>2$.

Finally, to check $4$ works is easy, if the number is of form $p^k$ and has $4$ or more divisors then $k\geq 3$ and so $p^3$ is the divisor we wanted. Otherwise there are primes $p$ and $q$ dividing $n$ and so $pq$ is the desired divisor.

Proving it works for $2$ should be much easier.

Comment: Oh lol, I understood the problem as: prove that $2$ and $4$ are the only numbers that satisfy: every number with more than $n$ divisors has a divisor with exactly $n$ divisors.

Comment: So you didn't answer my question, did you? Sorry for not phrasing the question in an intelligible way.